# Don't loose focus on background activity after opening dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am opening a dialog fragment on Button click in a activity. Now I don't want loose focus on my background activity after opening the dialog fragment. The background activity has a chat window so the edit text in that chat window should not loose focus, to be more precise one should be able to chat even when the dialog fragment is open. Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: Well service component is the way to go. Check the service documentation.

Comment: @WebInsight I've edited my question. Can you have look at it one more time and tell if service component can be used?

Comment: You can place one layout resembling a dialog on the center of the screen with visibility gone.Then when you do make it visible the edittext is also interactable :)

Comment: So did it worked?

Comment: Yeah it worked not exactly the way i wanted but almost. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ok I am writing the answer below. You can upvote and accept it. Doing this just for anyone else to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can place an individual layout( which is your dialog layout ) onto the center of the screen
(`gravity="center"` or `centerinParent="true"`)
 and set its visibility to invisible or gone.Then when you make the dialog layout appear, the edittext will be focusable as well.

I would encourage other answers which may be an alternative to this behavior which the OP wants.